# How to connect Sqlite database in android?I created sqlite db in mozilla firefox

Tags: android

am new to db in android. My DB name is bharath and my table name is employee. I dont know how to connect it. so kindly help me from the basics. Thank u.

Comment: Have you tried to figure that out by yourself? What have you tried?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5) tutorial : number 112 onwards
and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) class

you basically needs a private class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper class

and then you can use instance of this class to perform various db related operation using methods like

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                    KEY_SCALE + " TEXT NOT NULL);"                              
            );
```